# Why am I unable to reference a ref in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Why am I getting myRef not defined? I am not sure how to access a component from an external function.

When `displayTranscription(transcript)` is called I need to capture the text in the `<p>` and concat it to `totalText`.

```
var totalText = '';
const displayTranscription = (transcript) => {
  totalText = totalText + myRef.current.text;
  console.log('dispalyTranscript called');
  return transcript.elements.reduce((a, b) => {
    a += ` ${b.value}`;
    return a;
  }, '');
};

const StreamingCaptionViewer = () => {
  const myRef = createRef(null);
  const [transcript, setTranscript] = useState(null);
  const socket = useSocket('transcript', (data) => {
    console.log(`data recieved: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
    setTranscript(data);
  });

  const ErrorMessage = {
    color: 'red',
    fontSize: '13px',
  };

  return (
    <div className='w-full'>
      <p ref={myRef} style={ErrorMessage}>
        {transcript ? displayTranscription(transcript) : null}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Should you be using `useRef` instead of `createRef` in a functional component, so you're sure that the reference doesn't change across renders?

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't move the function inside the component and relay on the state `transcript` directly without any need to use ref. I'm sure this is the right why to implement this case.

and then to optimize your code convert the function to `useMemo` hook to reduce the re-calculations count.

Comment: Not sure what this means. It's provocative thought. ;)